# Dockerized MongoDB Replica Set Access Outside Container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

**Short Description of the Setup**

I have a one-member replica set (why? see bottom). The mongo service is running inside a docker container. In the [replica set config](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#start-each-member-of-the-replica-set-with-the-appropriate-options) each member is referenced by a hostname, since I am using a docker container I am using its name (`mongodb0`) as hostname. The mongodb port is forwarded to the host machine.

**Problem**

For debugging purposes I would like to access the db from outside the container. Just using `mongosh` works, although it seems it is not recognizing the instance as part of the replica set. Connecting a node driver to `mongodb0` does not work at all (to be expected, since the hostname is only resolved inside the container) however, I would think I can connect to `localhost:27017` which is the forwarded port (that's why `mongosh` is working) but it's throwing following error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb0
...
```

*Note I am using `localhost` in my node driver connection string.*

*Why am I using a replica set with only one member? Only a replica sets allows me to use the [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/).*

Comment: what is your connection string?  Did you include the replica set name?

Comment: Here is a single-member replica set docker image - https://hub.docker.com/r/simagix/mongo

Comment: @barrypicker inside the container my connection string is `mongodb://${username}:${password}@mongodb0:27017?replicaSet=rs0` outside it is `mongodb://${username}:${password}@localhost:27017?replicaSet=rs0`

Comment: @barrypicker there is some extra config I'd like to do with my db setup, so I'd rather not use this image. However, I just noticed a weird behavior: `mongosh 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs'` does not work whereas `mongosh 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'` does, which leads me to think there is something wrong with my mongo container setup. But using this container and another one within the same docker compose works fine. So it's gotta be something with resolving the replica set member hostname from outside, right? any ideas?

Comment: not sure if its relevant but I have mongo bindIp configured: `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

Comment: sometimes I need to add a slash at the end of my host definitions.  So for example: `mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0` vs. `mongodb://localhost:27017?replicaSet=rs0`.  Seems to be some parsing problem.  By the way, your not working most recent comment has the wrong replica set name - rs, instead of rs0.